# Run two MonetDB databases simoultaneously in Windows

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to run two MonetDB databases simoultaneously in Windows.

I changed the database name in M5server.bat to mydb, and added -database=mydb to mclient.bat

Then I copied the M5server.bat file and changed the farm to mydb2. I also copied the mclient.bat file and added -database=mydb2.

I run the two server bats to start the two databases and that seems to work fine (no errors).

Then I run the first mclient.bat and it connects to the server with no issues.

But when I run the copied mclient.bat and try to connect using user/password monetdb/monetdb, I get the following error and cannot connect:

> request for database 'mydb2', but this is database 'mydb', did
>   you mean to connect to monetdbd instead?

How to run two databases simoultaneously in Windows? How to connect to two databases at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different ports for different databases:

**Example db1:**

mserver5.bat file

```
--set "mapi_port=50001"
```

mclient.bat file

```
-p 50001
```

**Example db2:**

mserver5.bat file

```
--set "mapi_port=50002"
```

mclient.bat file

```
-p 50002
```